# If user1 content deleted, it dissapears from user2's feed automatically

Tags: php, ajax

So I have a social network I'm building and I have a question I'd like answering if somebody could help.

So lets say user1 deletes their post with ajax and it disappears in their feed instantly, but user2 in their friends hasn't refreshed their feed, and it still shows this exact post user1 has just deleted. 
How would I then go about removing that post that's been deleted without the 2nd user having to refresh the page. Would I do it the same way as loading new posts but search specifically for deleted posts in the feed then fade them out if it doesn't find a certain post by its id?

Comment: I would use a websocket connection for stuff like this instead of ajax

Comment: Is websocket connection more efficient for the server than ajax then? And what's the differences between the two?

Comment: websockets are "real time" and you can just push updates over the existing open connections instead of having to keep polling the server.

Comment: Facebook make heavy use of long-polling. And use comet. The problem with Websockets is that it isn't supported in older browsers and being it a social network it has to support anything and everything.

Comment: ok good luck support netscape navigator 1.0

Comment: Also even facebook doesn't support every browser out there

Answer (score 1):

If your application is so heavy on ajax client side interactions, I'd try [angular](https://angularjs.org/) or one of its relatives, as I believe it will save you much hassle.

Basically, if going the pure JS \ JQuery way, I'd probably go about having some kind of a timed function (something along the guidelines of a client-side thread) that would grab all posts in page (maybe even save it in a list, so you won't have to go through the DOM each time?) and update \ delete \ add the required posts.